# How to delete specific realm object using for loop

Tags: android, realm

I'm currently trying to delete specific realm object in my model using for loop,

but every time that i execute the `deleteFromRealm(i)` it stops the loop and I can no longer delete the other object.

I haven't tried any other options though.

```
final Realm realms = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realms.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                RealmResults<CashCountScoreModel> cashCountScoreModels =
                        CashCountScoreModel.getAll(realm);
                for (int i = 0; i < cashCountScoreModels.size(); i++) {
                    if (cashCountScoreModels.get(i) != null && cashCountScoreModels.get(i).isCashOnHand) {
                        Log.d("CheckName : pos -- ",  i +"~~" + cashCountScoreModels.get(i).isCashOnHand);
                        Log.d("CheckName : pos --",  i + "~~" + cashCountScoreModels.get(i).employeeName);
                        cashCountScoreModels.deleteFromRealm(i);
                    //    continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Whenever i try to run the app, and execute this specific code `cashCountScoreModels.deleteFromRealm(i);`, it stops the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `deleteFromRealm(i)` inside a loop because it always causes crash. Use this code instead:

```
    realms.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<CashCountScoreModel> results = CashCountScoreModel.getAll(realm);
            results.where().equalTo("isCashOnHand", true).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Realm you are using. But since 3.0.0, Realm collections are live and hence updated immediately. So, cashCountScoreModels.size() will return a count less upon every deletion. In your case, I suspect you have just 2 entries in the collection. You might want to use `OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot` instead. Try out following code.

```
final Realm realms = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realms.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                RealmResults<CashCountScoreModel> cashCountScoreModels = CashCountScoreModel.getAll(realm);
                OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot snapshot = cashCountScoreModels.createSnapshot();
                for (CashCountScoreModel cashCountScoreModel : snapshot) {
                    if (cashCountScoreModel != null && cashCountScoreModel.isCashOnHand) {
                        Log.d("CheckName : pos -- ",  i +"~~" + cashCountScoreModel.isCashOnHand);
                        Log.d("CheckName : pos --",  i + "~~" + cashCountScoreModel.employeeName);
                        cashCountScoreModel.deleteFromRealm();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Look for `Iterations & snapshots` on https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/ or the documentation available at https://realm.io/docs/java/3.0.0/api/io/realm/OrderedRealmCollection.html#loops to know more realtime update in collections and `OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot`

Comment: it's making my CashCountScoreModel to be an object, but my CashCountScoreModel is a class model.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because I think you want to delete multiple realm objects from a single execution block.
Try below code in execute block.

```
RealmResults<CashCountScoreModel> cashCountScoreModels=realm.where(CashCountScoreModel.class).equalTo(CashCountScoreModel.isCashOnHand,true).findAll();
cashCountScoreModels.deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Comment: it tried this one and returns : Invalid query: field 'true' not found in class 'CashCountScoreModel'.

my code is :

  RealmResults<CashCountScoreModel> cashCountScoreModels = CashCountScoreModel.getAll(realm);
                for (int i = 0; i <  cashCountScoreModels.size(); i++) {
                    RealmResults<CashCountScoreModel> cashCountScoreModelss=realm.where(CashCountScoreModel.class).equalTo(String.valueOf(cashCountScoreModels.get(i).isCashOnHand),true).findAll();
                    cashCountScoreModelss.deleteAllFromRealm();
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
RealmResults<CashCountScoreModel> cashCountScoreModels=realm.where(CashCountScoreModel.class).equalTo(CashCountScoreModel.isCashOnHand,true).findAll();
cashCountScoreModels.deleteAllFromRealm();
}
});
```

@Md. Nowshad Hasan  is Correct. Just run in Realm Thread.